# obtener consulta GET desde javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un problema estoy intenteado de obtener la query de una url actual desde javascript pero me da un problema.

Resultado que responde es:
`/pinturas?**0**=27&1=1&demo=1&sort_by=price-descending`

Url solicitada:
`localhost/category/pinturas?page=27&demo=1`

Al inicio de la query `pinturas?0=27` en el cero deberia ir page

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('select[class="form-control js-sort-by"]').change(function(){
    var vars = [], hash;
    var q = document.URL.split('?')[1];

    if(q != undefined){
        q = q.split('&');
        for(var i = 0; i < q.length; i++){
            hash = q[i].split('=');
            vars.push(hash[1]);
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
    }

    var params = vars;
    params['sort_by'] = $(this).val();
    var sort_params_array = [];

    for (var key in params) {
        if ($.inArray(key,['page'])==-1) {
            sort_params_array.push(key + '=' + params[key]);
        }
    }

    var sort_params = sort_params_array.join('&');
    alert(window.location.pathname + '?' + sort_params);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<label for="sort-by">Ordenar por: </label>
<select class="form-control js-sort-by" id="sort-by">
    <option value="price-ascending">Precio: Menor a Mayor</option>
    <option value="price-descending">Precio: Mayor a Menor</option>
    <option value="alpha-ascending">A - Z</option>
    <option value="alpha-descending">Z - A</option>
    <option value="created-descending">Más Nuevo al más Viejo</option>
    <option value="created-ascending">Más Viejo al más Nuevo</option>
    <option value="best-selling">Más Vendidos</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Estas tratando de eliminar `page` en `sort_params`?

Comment: no solo quiero obtener la consulta de GET que se envia desde la url de forma en array

Comment: ya lo resolvi era un error mio :(

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
function getParams(u,k){
 var p={};
 u.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,function(s,k,v){p[k]=v})
 return k?p[k]:p;
}

var url = "http://localhost/category/?page=27&demo=1";

var pl = getParams(location.search)
var pu = getParams(url);
var pp = getParams(url,"page")
var pd = getParams(url,"demo")

console.log(pl);
console.log(pu);
console.log(pp);
console.log(pd);
```